# Exporting feature class into multiple feature classes based on field ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, splitting

I have one shapefile, with 100 rows data. How to split to multiple feature class based on attribute I selected? I remember I can do it using GUI (old ArcMap) but now I can't. I use ArcMap 10.3.1. It's better if it's not Python script cause it's mostly used and simple process.

1. [This tool are not working](https://patriciamurrieta.wordpress.com/2011/02/08/converting-a-single-shapefile-into-several-split-by-attribute/)
2. Split Layer by Attribute tool. -> How to use this to achieve my goal?, cause it's only do selection.

Comment: How many classes do you want to split it into.  If you are only dealing with a small amount of classes, why not just select by attribute, then export data to a new feature class, then repeat for each attribute.

Comment: As i mentioned in my question there are 100 data, and I wont do that manually, and even so rather than use select by attribute I can just select each attribute directly from attribute table and export it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SplitLayerByAttributes](http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=15ca63aebb4647a4b07bc94f3d051da5) did help me. Just run the toolbox (It's python script, but at least already have GUI, I don't have to build it my self). I dont know why it's work while others don't, but so far my problem solved by using this tool.

Answer (score 3):

There appears to be an ArcMap 10.3.1 tool available on this page: http://www.umesc.usgs.gov/management/dss/split_by_attribute_tool.html

This is the direct link to the tool: 
http://www.umesc.usgs.gov/management/dss/split_by_attribute/FoxSplitByAttributeAddin10_3_1.zip

Comment: I did have the tool (an updated one also) and yes, It's not working. It runs, but whenever it done, I have Empty geodatabase result.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Are you selecting the features before you use the tool? If not, make sure you uncheck the "Only export selected features" checkbox before you run the tool.

Comment: yes I did select the features and check "only export selected features" and I did not select the features and uncheck "only..." simple way to say I did test all the option, even prefix and non prefix name, even change various output directory.